# hibernate.generate_statistics not working on spring

Tags: hibernate

```
configuration.setProperty("hibernate.generate_statistics", "true")
```

Everything fine but not able to get any stats in console .

where other property like `hibernate.show_sql` working fine except this .Am using Hibernate core 5.6.5.Final

Tried spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=true but no luck.

```
// Create a new Configuration instance
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

// Set the Hibernate properties, including generate_statistics
configuration.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase");
configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "myusername");
configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", "mypassword");
configuration.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
configuration.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
configuration.setProperty("hibernate.generate_statistics", "true");

// Build the SessionFactory from the Configuration
SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was in log4j2.properties files .
here's my correct log4j2 file

```
appenders = console
appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.target = SYSTEM_OUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] - %m%n

rootLogger.level = info
rootLogger.appenderRefs = stdout
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT

logger.hibernate.name = org.hibernate
logger.hibernate.level = info

logger.hibernate.SQL.name = org.hibernate.SQL
logger.hibernate.SQL.level = debug

logger.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.name = org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql
logger.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.level = trace

logger.hibernate.stat.name = org.hibernate.stat
logger.hibernate.stat.level = debug

logger.hibernate.SQL_SLOW.name = org.hibernate.SQL_SLOW
logger.hibernate.SQL_SLOW.level = info

logger.hibernate.cache.name = org.hibernate.cache
logger.hibernate.cache.level = debug
```

output :

```
12:36:46,874 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener] - Session Metrics {
    11112379 nanoseconds spent acquiring 18 JDBC connections;
    10659621 nanoseconds spent releasing 18 JDBC connections;
    71961252 nanoseconds spent preparing 38 JDBC statements;
    68823399 nanoseconds spent executing 34 JDBC statements;
    59534785 nanoseconds spent executing 4 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    13160247683 nanoseconds spent executing 1 flushes (flushing a total of 25 entities and 1 collections);
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
```